# How to get white text in actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make this black text white, but I'm not sure how.

[image: Screenshot]

Currently my code is like this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MainActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MainActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/icsb</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

PS: This is not ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Those are action buttons, not titles. I think this is controlled the `android:actionButtonStyle` attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your parent theme to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and action bar parent style to `@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar`. The parent theme controls the color of action bar text, so that on a dark action bar, the text has a light color.